# How to Decorate Edit Texts in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

I have been trying to design an Edit Text of shape similar to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ibxP.png) above... can anybody tell me how to create this shape?

[image]

Comment: please post what you've tried so far, makes it easier for others to get started with helping

Comment: use TexInputLayoutEditText to achieve this design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this in your layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/label"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: please upvoto also